# How to unregister a field in in react-final-form?

Tags: react-final-form

There is documentation on how to register a field but I don't see anything on how to unregister a field after it's been rendered. Anyone know how I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just unmount (stop rendering) the `Field` component or the component using `useField()`.

Answer (score 1):

> destroyOnUnregister Optional.
>
> boolean If true, the value of a field will be destroyed when that
> field is unregistered. Defaults to false. Can be useful when creating
> dynamic forms where only form values displayed need be submitted.

So just set this on your Form:

```js
<Form destroyOnUnregister .... />
```

https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/Config#destroyonunregister